# hibernate insert duplicate key, i use mysql

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

this is my entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_info")
@DynamicInsert
@DynamicUpdate

public class BasicUserInfo {

@Id @GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "u_id")
private int id;

@Column(name = "u_openid",unique = true)
private String openid;

@Transient
private String access_token;
@Column(name = "u_nickname")
private String nickname;

@Column(name = "u_sex")
private int sex;

@Column(name = "u_province")
private String province;

@Column(name = "u_city")
private String city;

@Column(name = "u_country")
private String country;

@Column(name = "u_headimgurl")
private String headimgurl;

public String getNickname() {
    return nickname;
}

public void setNickname(String nickname) {
    this.nickname = nickname;
}

public int getSex() {
    return sex;
}

public void setSex(int sex) {
    this.sex = sex;
}

public String getProvince() {
    return province;
}

public void setProvince(String province) {
    this.province = province;
}

public String getCity() {
    return city;
}

public void setCity(String city) {
    this.city = city;
}

public String getCountry() {
    return country;
}

public void setCountry(String country) {
    this.country = country;
}

public String getHeadimgurl() {
    return headimgurl;
}

public void setHeadimgurl(String headimgurl) {
    this.headimgurl = headimgurl;
}

public String getAccess_token() {
    return access_token;
}

public void setAccess_token(String access_token) {
    this.access_token = access_token;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getOpenid() {
    return openid;
}

public void setOpenid(String openid) {
    this.openid = openid;
}

public BasicUserInfo() {
}



   public BasicUserInfo(String openid) {
        this.openid = openid;
    }

}
public class OpenIdDAO {

    public static void saveOrUpdate(BasicUserInfo basicUserInfo) {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFacory().openSession();
        Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
        Query query = session.createQuery("from BasicUserInfo  b where b.openid = :openid");
        query.setProperties(basicUserInfo);
        List<BasicUserInfo> list = query.list();
        transaction.commit();
        session.close();
        if (list != null && list.size() > 0) {
            //如果已经存在记录
            BasicUserInfo basicUserInfo1 = list.get(0);
            basicUserInfo.setId(basicUserInfo1.getId());
            CRUDHelper.update(basicUserInfo);
        } else {
            CRUDHelper.save(basicUserInfo);
        }
    }
}
```

Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        user_info
        (u_openid, u_sex, u_id) 
    values
        (?, ?, ?)
[org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] - SQL Error: 1062, SQLState: 23000
[org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] - Duplicate entry '36' for key 'PRIMARY'

but there're nearly 2000 records in my databases,so do you have some ideas about this?